# Recovering private key from certificate signing request

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Private and Public key has been deleted from the keychain.

I do, however, have the file .certSigningRequest.

Is there a way I can get the private key in pem encoded format from .certSigningRequest?

Comment: You can't get the *private*key in any format from the CSR because it's not *in* the CSR; see @kitty answer. If you did (or do?) have it *some* format, *reformatting* to PEM would be easy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.

The `.certSigningRequest` is what would have been sent to your chosen Certficate Authority (CA). The Certificate Authority would then have, after verifying that you do in fact own the site you're securing, signed your certificate, generating the signed certificate that you're now, unfortunately, missing.

The point of an SSL certificate is to prove that you are who you say you are, among other things. Having a CA sign your certificate lends credence to it, which is essentially why you can't regenerate your certificate with just your `.certSigningRequest`.

**Request a New Cert from Your CA**

Many CAs will take pity on you and allow you to request a new signed certificate from them. This will, of course, depend on who your CA is, as will the route you need to take in order to acquire the new certificate.

If your CA does allow it, you won't be able to use the `.certSigningRequest` you still have -- that file is now useless without the keys that went with it. You'll need to generate a new keypair && Certificate Signing Request, which request you'll then forward to the CA.

**Generate a New Self-Signed Certificate**

If that isn't an option, or if you're uninterested in regaining that extra credence from a CA, you can generate a self-signed certificate by executing the following commands (assuming you're using Debian-based Linux/Apache):

```
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.key
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache*
```

This will generate a self-signed SSL certificate that will be good for 1 year (`-days 365`). The main down-side to a self-signed certificate is that many browsers will display that pesky pop-up that warns the user that the site's identity can't be verified.

Comment: Two smallish points: The CA will generate a *user* or formally End-Entity cert, not a root (its root already exists and has for usually a decade or more). If the CA lets you submit a new CSR, which as you say is fairly common, you must first generate a *new keypair and the CSR* for it, and submit that.